# Using Redux for dynamic wizard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am considering using React to implement a dynamic wizard in my application. Following are the use cases:

1. The flow is composed of steps ( or pages ) which will not have a fixed order. The flow's order can change based on business logic.
2. Each step is composed of components which work in a plug and play fashion. A component can be reused across the same step or multiple steps with different configurations based on business requirement. For eg. Address can be a component and can be used in the same step in the form of Credit card billing address or Bank account business address.
3. Each component is tied up to a backend api for data persistence.
4. The flow is suppose to maintain the user state. State like the steps completed, continue and save features.

In my opinion, following will be the template of this flow:

```
<App>
    <Flow>
        <Step1>
            <Component1 ...props/>
            <Component2 ...props/>
            <Component3 ...props/>
        </Step1>
        <Step2>
            <Component1 ...props/>
            <Component4 ...props/>
            <Component5 ...props/>
        </Step2>
    </Flow>
</App>
```

The order of Steps and Components in the above markup can be dynamic.

I am not sure if react is the right candidate for this situation due to the following considerations:

1. Server will decide the order and composition of steps and components because downstream services are invoked to determine the flow. React will not be able to manage this.
2. Since component's html markup will reside inside JSX, all the components will have to be bundled up upfront. I am not sure if I can leverage tree shaking to optimize the bundles based on url routes.
3. User state will be handled by both Server and React. Based on user state, Server will decide the ordering of steps and components, and React will own the rendering logic on the front end.

My opinion is that this a common pattern in enterprise applications. I am looking for examples on how to use react in such setting.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some thinking over this, since Im triying to implement something similar to my application. Here is what I came up with:

When using a wizard form, you need to wrap. up the steps by the wizard.

In my case I have to send a request to the server and decide whether or not i need a new step. For this to happen dynamically in react you have to create a key for each response received from server.

so everytime a new step response is receieved create in your redux state:

```
 state={
  steps:[{key, step1},{key,step2}]
}
```

everytime a new step is receieved update state by pushing new key value pair. if you save the questions like this you can click on previous button and navigate to specific key.

Lastly, wrap the wizard by a component and map your steps. Everytime new step receieved from server it'll dynamically create a new step.

```
<YourComponent>
<Wizard>
 {this.props.(yourReduxState).steps.map(eachStep=>
  <Steps  key={eachStep.key}/>
)
</Wizard>
</YourComponent>
```

And handle all the steps receieved from the server in the same component, which in this case `<Steps />`